# From an API call, how can I grab a field and see how many times that value is being repeated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, count

Code:

```
    var textArray = new Array();
    var allText = results.data._contained.text;
    for (var i = 0; i < allText.length; i++) {
        var text1 = allText[i];
        var textHtml = "<div id='text_item'>";
        textHtml += "<span class='some_div'>{0}</span>".replace("{0}", text1.text_is);
        textHtml += "</div>";
        textArray.push(text1.texts.priority);

        $("#text_box").append(textHtml);
    }

    if (foo === 'Some text') {
        document.write("match");
    } else {
        document.write("not match");
    }

}
```

I have the above logic which is working fine but I am stuck on something I haven't done before.

This is what I want to do:

The span .some_div will contain string values.  What I want to do is count how many times the same value repeats.  How can I do that?

Example: let's the say the value is "Medicine" and it repeats 10 times in independently in .some_div.  How can I return a count of how many times it has repeated?

Comment: You probably want to post more information so we can reproduce the scenario, it is not clear (at least to me) what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.split function to achieve that, if text1.text_is (which is the content of .some_div span) is of type String.

```
var wordsCount = {};
var allWords = text1.text_is.split(" ") //split by space or the delimiter of the words.
for (var i = 0, l = allWords.length; i < l; i++)
{
    var word = allWords[i];
    wordsCount[word] = (wordsCount[word] || 0) + 1;
}
```

Good luck

Comment: Yup but in this case you are specifying "Medicine" the values are dynamic so I need to be able to do this dynamically.

Comment: Do you mean that you need to count how many each word in the string is repeated ?

Comment: Yees, so let's say I have this <span>Medicine</span> <span>Something</span> I want to be able to say that Medicine was repeated 2 times and something was repeated once.

Comment: @KPO why is Medicine repeated 2 times in this case?

Comment: @dave I used that just as an example.  The thing is on the site there could be say 10k people and they submit values.  So I want to be able to count common answers and say that "medicine" was submitted 2 times, etc...

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. Before i edited the answer, it should be text1.text_is.split("Medicine").length - 1. Minus one, not plus one.

Comment: @Oday Thanks.  I tried it but i get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @Oday the problem seems to be with this line for (int i = 0, l = allWords.length; i < l; i++)

Comment: Oooops int instead of var :). Currently working on C# :P

Comment: @Oday Thanks but now i get this error: Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient and convenient way to do this is to use [string.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a regular expression. This has the added benefit of allowing case-insensitivity.

```js
function countWords(text) {
  var resultArray = [];
  var text = $(".some_div").text(); //store the original text
  text = text.replace(/\W/g, " "); //replace non-alphanumerics with a whitespace
  text = text.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " "); //replace more than one space with a single space

  while (text.length > 0) {
    var index = text.indexOf(" "); //find the first space
  
    if (index === 0) {
      text = text.slice(1, text.length); //this is a leading space, skip it
    } else {
      var wordToMatch = text.slice(0, index); //find the first word
      var regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, "gi"); //create case-insensitive regular expression with the word
      var wordCount = text.match(regex).length; //get number of word occurences
      resultArray.push({ word: wordToMatch, count: wordCount }); //store the result for this word
      text = text.replace(regex, ""); //remove this word from the input text
      text = text.replace(/\s{2,}/g, " "); //replace more than one space with a single space again
    } 
  }

  return resultArray;
}

countWords($(".some_div").text()).forEach(function(item) {
  $("#result").append(item.word + ": " + item.count + "<br/>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class='some_div'>The field of Medicine is a medicine Field</span>
<br/>
<div id="result"></div>
```